# Распарсить JSON в jQuery ($.ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

В общем вот я пытаюсь распарсить JSON данные, который возвращаются из PHP в jQuery ($.ajax)

В jQuery имеем такой код

```
$.ajax({
    url:"rate.php",
    type:"POST",
    success:function(result){   //роль играет только этот блок
        $("#rezhere").html(result)
    }
});
```

А в PHP собственно получаем кое-какие данные из базы, засовываем их в массив, после чего сериализауем в JSON строку с помощью **json_encode()**:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2";
$rez = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rez)) {
    $arr[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);  //переводим массив в json строку
```

В jQuery нам возвращается вот такое безобразие:

```
[{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"someImg.jpg","filename":"someImg.jpg"},{"0":"10","id":"10","1":"someImg2.jpg","filename":"someImg2.jpg"}]
```

Для удобства сделал снимок в нормальном виде: 
[image]

Имею 2 вопроса:

1. Это нормально что он возвращает массив в двух видах? Ассоциативном, и.. простом, числовом.  Мне бы и просто ассоциативного хватило.
2. И самое главное - как в jQuery нормально спарсить эти данные? Как видите мне приходит 2 картинки, нужно их обе присоединить к IMG тегам. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. используй вместо mysql_fetch_array функцию mysql_fetch_assoc
2. отправь перед echo заголовок header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
3. не знаю как у тебя выглядит html и как тебе нужно менять, но на success постаавь функцию типа такой:

function(result){
    var images = $("#rezhere").find('img');  //находим все картинки в #rezhere
    images.eq(0).attr('src', result[0].filename); // выставляем первой картинке 1-ый путь 
    images.eq(1).attr('src', result[1].filename); // выставляем второй картинке 2-ый путь
}

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы прям как в воду глядели.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы с сервера принимался json, *можно* в параметры запроса добавить `dataType: 'json'`. То есть сейчас он угадывает, а так будет 100% его принимать.

Чтобы отправлялся только ассоциативный, нужно брать из mysql ассоциативный массив :) А это ф-ция `mysql_fetch_assoc` (`mysql_fetch_object` тоже должна нормально обрабатываться).

Парсить данные не надо, они уже объектом будут в момент success.

То есть:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"rate.php",
  type:"POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(result){ 
    var images = '';
    for (var n in result)
      images += '<img src="'+result[n].filename+'" />';
    $("#rezhere").html(images);
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
$rez = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez))
  $arr[]=$row;
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Особенно удобно когда у тебя весь XHR работает с JSON. Настроить 1 раз и забыть (тогда может даже появиться чувство того что происходит какая-то магия :DDD)

Comment: И вам огромное спасибо! Так всё расписали, супер!  
  
Но до конца не хотело работать, пока не указал  
  
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

как посоветовал RedMonkey. Сейчас обоим рейтинга накидаю :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Всё правильно.
2. Вот так.

   ```
   $.post('rate.php', function (data) {
     alert(data[0].filename)
   }, 'json');
   ```

Comment: У редактора со списками косяки =/ я не знаю, как их обойти. Предложу убрать список)

Comment: Все работает, надо было только вместо 1пустой строки сделать по 2 и вместо 4 пробелов сделать 8 xDDD

Comment: Жесткач. Вручаю @AlexWindHope бубен.